# How to close popover-form with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, alert

From indeed.com I try to get automatically the job titles, employers and descriptions.

It works fine, until the loop gets on the second page.

A popover-form appears, where I should press the "Nein, danke." Button, to go on. When this altert appears, the loop just stops.

My code looks like this and works fine until the second page:

```
# Import the packages
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import gensim

# Start Webscraping
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.maximize_window()

# List with indeed URLs to scrape through
indeed_url_list = ['https://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=data&l=&sort=date',
                   'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=10',
                   'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=20',
                   'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=30',
                   'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=40'
                   ]

# Empty lists that will be filled
indeed_job_links = []         # list with links to scrape through
indeed_job_titles = []        # list with job titles
indeed_job_employers = []     # list with job employers
indeed_job_descriptions = []  # list with job descriptions

# for loop for scraping
for indeed_page in indeed_url_list:    
    driver.get(indeed_page)    
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard" or @class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row sjlast result clickcard" or @class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard vjs-highlight" or @class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard lastRow row result clickcard" or @class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard vjs-highlight"]/*/a')     

    # get job link to list
    for i in list(links):
        indeed_job_links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

    # scrape through the job descriptions
    for link in links:
        # open the link
        link.click()
        sleep(0.6)
        # get job title to list
        indeed_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="vjs-jobtitle"]').text
        indeed_job_titles.append(indeed_title)
        # get job employer to list
        indeed_employer = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="vjs-cn"]').text
        indeed_job_employers.append(indeed_employer)
        # get job description to list
        indeed_description = ' '.join(word_tokenize(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="vjs-desc"]').text))
        indeed_job_descriptions.append(indeed_description)
```

I really don't know what to do here. Does anybody have an idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an actual alert, this should work for you. For reference, [here is the relevant section of the Selenium documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#popup-dialogs)

```
alertObj = driver.switch_to.alert
alertObj.accept()
alertObj.dismiss()
```

---

I deal with alerts a lot while testing our applications. I've found they can be quite unreliable in how long it takes the webpage to render them. Here's my standard implimentation.

```
def test(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name(a).clear()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name(b).send_keys()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name(c).click()

    # wait for an alert box to render
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        alert_text = self.driver.switch_to.alert
        self.assertEqual('alert text', alert_text.text)
        self.driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
    except TypeError:
        [do stuff]
```

Comment: Maybe it is not an alert, but a pop-up window. The important thing is, that suddenly it appears and normally I would have to press the "Nein, danke." Button to move on. So my loop just stops.  Can your code do exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the pop-over that you referenced on indeed.com.
Its a dialog not a browser alert, so the previous answer, where you switch to alert, won't work.

```
driver.switch_to.alert
```

will only work in cases of the JavaScript alerts.

What you see on indeed.com is a HTML dialog and it should be processed just like any other page elements.

The very first time you change the page, you know that dialog will show up, so wait for it and close it. I'm not sure if it will show up again after you change N number of pages. But if it does, instead of closing it, you may want to consider giving it an email to stop it from popping up. Or every time you change the page, you can check if dialog is shown and close it - this is less optimal.

Here is your code, slightly tidied up with support for closing the dialog:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class IndeedScraper:

    # List with indeed URLs to scrape through
    INDEED_URL_LIST = ['https://de.indeed.com/Jobs?q=data&l=&sort=date',
                       'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=10',
                       'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=20',
                       'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=30',
                       'https://de.indeed.com/jobs?q=Data&sort=date&start=40'
                       ]

    # Empty lists that will be filled
    INDEED_JOB_LINKS = []         # list with links to scrape through
    INDEED_JOB_TITLES = []        # list with job titles
    INDEED_JOB_EMPLOYERS = []     # list with job employers
    INDEED_JOB_DESCRIPTIONS = []  # list with job descriptions

    def __init__(self, driver):

        self.driver = driver
        self.have_closed_dialog = False

    def scrape(self):

        for indeed_page in IndeedScraper.INDEED_URL_LIST:
            self.driver.get(indeed_page)
            links = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                '//div[@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard" or '
                '@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row sjlast result clickcard" or '
                '@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard vjs-highlight" or '
                '@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard lastRow row result clickcard" or '
                '@class="jobsearch-SerpJobCard row result clickcard vjs-highlight"]/*/a')

            # get job link to list
            for i in list(links):
                IndeedScraper.INDEED_JOB_LINKS.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

            # scrape through the job descriptions
            for link in links:
                # open the link
                link.click()
                sleep(0.6)
                self.__close_dialog()  # Will close the dialog once and only if its shown
                self.__get_job_titles()
                self.__get_job_employers()
                self.__get_job_descriptions()

    def __is_dialog_shown(self):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 0.3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "popover-foreground")))
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def __close_dialog(self):

        if not self.have_closed_dialog and self.__is_dialog_shown():
            self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "popover-link-x").click()
            self.have_closed_dialog = True
        return self

    def __get_job_titles(self):
        # get job title to list
        IndeedScraper.INDEED_JOB_TITLES.append(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="vjs-jobtitle"]').text)
        return self

    def __get_job_employers(self):
        # get job employer to list
        IndeedScraper.INDEED_JOB_EMPLOYERS.append(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="vjs-cn"]').text)
        return self

    def __get_job_descriptions(self):
        # get job description to list
        description = ' '.join(word_tokenize(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="vjs-desc"]').text))
        IndeedScraper.INDEED_JOB_DESCRIPTIONS.append(description)
        return self


if "__main__" == __name__:

    driver = webdriver.Safari()
    driver.maximize_window()
    scraper = IndeedScraper(driver)
    scraper.scrape()
```

Comment: Thanks Artur and sorry for my late answer. I was suddenly stuck in a new project, but now I have time to go on with the webscraping. I will try your idea out. Thanks a lot.